# Storing sha3 hash in a useful way

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, bytes

I'm trying to store the sha3 hash of a string in a struct.

The problem is that its size exceeds what fits into a `bytes32` type. As such, the alternative would be to have it in a `bytes[]` or `string[]`. The problem here is then that it can't be easily returned from a function.

One option would be to split the hash in two and save it like

```
struct hash {
    bytes32 hash1;
    bytes32 hash2;
}
```

This looks a bit bad though, I think.

Is there a common workaround for this issue?

Comment: Are you creating sha3 hash in contract using solidity ?

Comment: No, outside the contract in a node js app.

Comment: I would suggest you to stick with solidity or web3 for generating hashes (sha3(x) in solidity / web3.sha3(x) which both fits into byte32) . And what is the length of hash you generate from Node js ,Let me see if i can help ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm generating a hash with `web3.sha3` but on nodejs. I then want to send that hash to the contract on the blockchain.

Comment: I guess then it must fit into bytes32 , As per the documentation it returns an hash of 32 bytes. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API and also make sure its not hex encoded.

Comment: You're right. I got confused it seemed like the hash stored on-chain was shortened. Sorry about that thanks a lot for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sha3 hash generated by web3 or solidity fits into bytes32 and don't require any special datatype to hold the has generated.

Reference : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API